# the file or assembly system could not be loaded Runtime CompilerServices Unsafe

Tags: c#

I am doing the secondary development of BIMBase. The ORM used is FreeSql and the database is PostgreSQL. However, when I call FreeSql query and other functions in KeyIn, the program always reports an error: the file or assembly [System. Runtime. CompilerServices. Unsafe]. Version=4.0.4.1, but after I change the version of [System. Runtime. CompilerServices. Unsafe] to 4.0.4.1, the error is reported that the file or assembly system could not be loaded Runtime CompilerServices Unsafe Version=4.0.5.0

Switch the version of [System.runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have different libraries that use different versions of the compilerServices. So one or the other is failing to load.

There are assembly binding redirects that can be used to tell the runtime to load a specific version of a library, even if a older version is requested. These are listed in the app.config file, and are normally created by default when needed.

it might look something like

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.5.0" newVersion="4.0.5.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

I would start by checking if you have such a redirect, and check if the version numbers are as you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. My question has been resolved